# DocuSign - How to get a specific page?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I'm using C# to grab the document from envelopesapi.getdocument(). It returns a  stream which is great for saving the whole envelope. My question is how do I only grab the first page of the first document? Is there a way that supports this?

Comment: Don't understand the downvote without a reason why...

Comment: Can you please share why you want to grab a specific page of the document?

Comment: The first page of the document contains information that I'd like to save separately from the whole document combined.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling GET `/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{documentId}/pages/{pageNumber}`

Comment: After talking with DocuSign, it does seem like this is the only way. They actually replied with having the template itself to be split up into two documents (the first page being one document, and the rest being a separate document). Thanks Amit!